# UIScrollView scrollViewWillBeginDragging not called when content size small

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

UIScrollView delegate method not called when its content size is small. Is there any way to get event of `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Comment: uiscrollview will not scroll if content size is smaller than scrollview size. You might need a gesture recogniser in this case

Comment: If you set `.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true` and/or `sv.alwaysBounceVertical = true`, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` **will** be called even if the content is not enough to require scrolling. So, the question is: ***why*** do you want it called if there is nothing to scroll?

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement single finger double finger behaviour, lets say content is small in some case, I would expect it should trigger scrollViewWillBeginDragging because I am using this delegate method to handle single/double finger gesture on UIScrollView

Comment: Thanks @DonMag for suggestion .alwaysBounceHorizontal = true attributes works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix it, I feel that UIScrollView behaviour to not allow scroll for smaller content is logical. In my case, requirement was to get `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` method. I am able to fix it after setting scrollview property

```
.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
```

Thank you @DonMag for suggestion.